# Excel Add-in, when to check for updates?

Tags: excel, vba

I've made a useful Excel VBA add-in that I'm almost ready to publish. I only have one problem. I want the add-in to check for updates whenever it is ran, and to notify the user if they're using an old version.

I have written a public sub that will check my website for the update using internet explorer automation. It is working fine when I run it manually.

My issue is, when should I call the `CheckForUpdate()` sub? I've tried putting it in `Workbook_Open()`, but the issue I've found is that if it takes too long, it blocks Excel from loading properly.

Is there a standard way that add-in writers check for updates? Why does Excel not load up a workbook when I have code in `Workbook_Open()`?

Thanks!

**Edit**: Here is my entire code. If this is added to an add-in workbook, and then the add-in is activated, I can't open any Excel files.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call CheckForUpdate
End Sub

Public Sub CheckForUpdate()
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    ie.Visible = False
    ie.navigate "https://example.com/checkforupdate"

    Do While ie.readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Set HTML = ie.document
    If HTML.DocumentElement.innerHTML = "update is available" Then
        MsgBox "An update is ready. Go get it!"
    Else
        MsgBox "no update"
    End If

    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Update**: I've tested on three computers now. 2 of them have Excel 2013 and the problem happens. One has Excel 2016 and it doesn't have the problem. I want to support all Excel versions, so I still need a work around.

Comment: I hope your update checker exits gracefully when the user is not connected to the internet.

Comment: Show the `CheckForUpdate()` code. Which line of the code takes the longest time? You should run check in another process, or via XHR in asynchronous mode.

Comment: If it's interfering with `Workbook_Open()`, why not just use `Application.OnTime` to schedule it for 10-15 seconds after the workbook loads?

Comment: How about an asynchronous VBScript (that is bundled with the add-in) which is launched by the open event. Excel can keep on running while the VBScript is running in its own thread. The VBScript can popup a message if an update is available.

Comment: @omegastripes I added some code.

Comment: @YowE3K Yes. I omitted error checking in my example, but I'll have it in my production code.

Comment: @Comintern I can't get that to work. It says it can't find the macro. I think it's looking in the open workbook and not the add-in workbook.

Comment: @JohnColeman I'm not sure how to do that. How do I make an asynchronous VBScript?

Comment: You actually don't need to package the VBScript separately if you go that route (you can generate it at runtime).  There's an example of something similar to what @JohnColeman was referring to [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29869308/4088852).

Comment: Actually, the internetexplorer object has a set of events that get triggered. I'd add a class module that handles the call to IE and responds to its events. That way the call becomes asynchronous all by itself. You do have to use early binding then however. The NavigateComplete2 event sounds most promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I ran your code and reproduced the issue, with Excel 2013. I didn't test on any other version.

It looks like what happens is if your code runs before a workbook is visible, it causes problems. I think it has more to do with the IE part, than anything else.

I tried using `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "CheckForUpdate"`. The problem with that is that if the user starts excel and out waits the timer before opening a workbook, you have exactly the same problem. I suspect the persons suggesting asynchronous VBScript will have exactly the same issue, but in a much more complicated way.

So let's go simple. You asked for a better place to put your code than `Workbook_Open()`. There is one.

Here's what worked for me:

Start a new add-in project. Add your `CheckForUpdates` function to a new module. Add the following code to `ThisWorkbook`.

```
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub App_WorkbookActivate(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    CheckForUpdate
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set App = Application
End Sub
```

With this code, your update procedure will run when a workbook is activated. It appears to not cause problems there.

Please let me know if that works. Good luck.