# Multithreading for Google Results VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba, multithreading

For a university research project, I plan to run a larger number of data requests with a total of c. 3,000 different spreadsheets, each including about 800-1,000 unique data requests.

Aim of the code is to get the number of Google News results for certain search terms within specific time frames, as for instance the results for "Elon Musk" between 01/01/2015 and 12/31/2015.

I have so far constructed a code that works relatively well with a single-threaded approach but would, given the large number of data requests, take weeks for the 3,000 spreadsheets to be completed (Google is occasionally blocking the requests given the sheer number of search queries but this is something generally manageable).

On the other hand, I have read that there is not "native" option in VBA to go for a time saving multi-threading approach, while several suggestions exist to work around this lack of a real multi-threading function. None of them has however really worked for my case so far.

Is there any practicable option to have the code below send out several Google requests at a time? This would allow the data collection in a much shorter time span. As mentioned, I have already been through a number of complex "out of the box" multi-threading solutions, of which none really worked.

```
Option Explicit 

Sub TermCheck()
Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
Dim start_time As Date
Dim end_time As Date
Dim var As String
Dim var1 As Object

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim cookie As String
Dim result_cookie As String

start_time = Time
Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

For i = 62 To lastRow

url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Cells(i, 3) & "&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A" & Cells(i, 4) & "%2Ccd_max%3A" & Cells(i, 5) & "&tbm=nws"

Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
XMLHTTP.send

Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.responseText
Set objResultDiv = html.getElementById("rso")
Set var1 = html.getElementById("resultStats")
If Not var1 Is Nothing Then
Cells(i, 6).Value = var1.innerText

End If

DoEvents
Next

end_time = Time
Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)

End Sub
```

Comment: migrate the code to a VSTO add-in and leverage the .net framework is an option

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29869308/4088852) for a possible VBA approach, but this would be much easier from .NET as mentioned above.

Comment: @sous2817 Thanks for your feedback. I have checked a .NET solution but it seems to be quite complex. Is there any “simple” way to apply the approach?

Comment: "Simple" as in "spoon-feed me with some code I can copy-pasta into my VBA editor and walk away with a working multi-threaded solution"? Nope, there isn't.

Comment: How are the proven solutions not working for you exactly? VBA runs on a single thread, so the best you can get is an object-oriented *asynchronous* solution, which would still be single-threaded.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon VBA multi-threading seems to be a general topic in this community and I am certainly not the only member looking for a feasible solution. Maybe the word “simple” was misleading, but I am looking for a practicable approach (not code but a strategy) for a researcher who does not have years of coding experience yet.

Comment: If you think the .NET solution is "complex", then any VBA solution is going to completely redefine your definition of "complex"...

Comment: @MathieuGuindon For me it is all about saving time given the large number of data requests. I hence need a solution that can ideally speed up the population of the sheets by a 10x factor. I have gone down the asynchronous approach already test-wise through an open source plug-in - it however did not yield any time savings when running the code.

Comment: Uh, so what is the question then? If you aren't looking for an asynchronous answer, what exactly do you mean by "Multithreading"?

Comment: VBA in Excel is inherently single-threaded - any MT solution is going to be a rather complicated hack involving VBScript or some other means of executing VBScript/VBA code out-of-process, and somehow synchronizing it back into one place. Or, a complete rewrite in .NET code that offloads the HTTP requests to background threads, and synchronizes the results back onto the main/UI thread to write the output to Excel or yield it to some VBA code. There is no "simple" solution for this, other than using the right tools for the job - VBA was never really meant to do massive-scale web-scraping.

Comment: @Comintern Running several requests at the same time, which is yielding a significant (!) reduction in time to run the code. As mentioned, I have tried this approach without any real time saving.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking then.

Comment: Make 62 copies of your workbook and assign each one a specific row to process. Open each workbook, fire off the code. While they're doing their work, write some code to scarf the results from those 62 parallel processes to copy/pasta the data into one massive workbook (or, better yet, a database).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon .NET could the the most viable option then after all. Again, I am thinking practically in the fastest way to populate the tables (time to migrate to .NET offset by the possible time savings in running the code after the migration).

Comment: In any case, I'd warmly recommend reading [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513). Whiteboard "general approach" discussions are well out of scope for this site, [un?]fortunately.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Understood. There seems to be no straightforward/standard answer in this case, that’s why I used an open question.

Comment: I think python is a good option for multi-threading and there are lots of examples on SO and CodeReview. Scrapy in particular is popular for web-scraping at scale.

Comment: Also, watch the start of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zinZmE3Ogk) when making your decision about threading as it may not be the optimal solution for handling your concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track by consolidating your data upfront, this is often a good idea for most projects. I'm not so sure you should give up on Async requests so quickly, have a go at this code below and see if that helps speed up your project.

I assumed that dates where in Columns D and E, so I mocked up my data to this idea. I also hard coded 'Elon Musk' in there to make things easier testing. You probably need to change this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TermCheck(RunAsync As Boolean)
    Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE As Long = 4
    Dim url             As String
    Dim WebRequest      As Object
    Dim WebRequests     As Object
    Dim CellIndex       As Variant
    Dim Document        As Object
    Dim ResultStat      As Object
    Dim ws              As Worksheet
    Dim StartDate       As Date
    Dim EndDate         As Date
    Dim i               As Long

    StartDate = #1/1/2015#
    EndDate = #1/2/2015#

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Set WebRequests = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For i = 1 To 30
        'Change URL here
        url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=Elon%20Musk" & _
              "&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A" & Replace(Format(ws.Cells(i, 4), "m/d/yyyy"), "/", "%2F") & _
              "%2Ccd_max%3A" & Replace(Format(ws.Cells(i, 5), "m/d/yyyy"), "/", "%2F") & "&tbm=nws"

        Set WebRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        With WebRequest
            .Open "GET", url, RunAsync
            .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
            .send
        End With
        StartDate = DateAdd("d", 1, StartDate)
        EndDate = DateAdd("d", 1, EndDate)
        WebRequests.Add i, WebRequest
    Next

    For Each CellIndex In WebRequests.Keys
        Set WebRequest = WebRequests(CellIndex)

        While WebRequest.Readystate <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

        If WebRequest.Status = 200 Then
            Set Document = CreateObject("htmlfile")
            Document.body.innerhtml = WebRequest.ResponseText
            Set ResultStat = Document.getElementById("resultStats")
            'Missing equals sign was here
            If Not ResultStat Is Nothing Then ws.Cells(CellIndex, 6).Value2 = ResultStat.innertext
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Sub TestRunRequests()
    'Run it Synchronous
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim MyTimer As Double
    MyTimer = Timer
    TermCheck False
    Debug.Print "Synchronous took: " & Timer - MyTimer

    'Run it Asynchronous
    MyTimer = Timer
    TermCheck True
    Debug.Print "Asynchronous took: " & Timer - MyTimer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Here are my the timings (in seconds) I got when I did 100 Requests for each method (async and sync):

```
Synchronous took: 44.5625
Asynchronous took: 22.46875
```

Comment: Thanks for your input and efforts. I have tried to apply your version but am not receiving any results with it (also when adjusting the respective spreadsheet names, cells for input and output etc.). I guess the simultaneous covering of different spreadsheets seems to be the most feasible solution for the moment.

Comment: Thanks again for your effort but it is still not yielding results with my sheet. I think I will continue to develop/edit the approach I was working on...

Answer (score 0):

This may rather be the "pedestrian way" regarding a time saving approach but I decided to paste all relevant spreadsheets into one major Excel file. When amending the code to cover all spreadsheets simultaneously (and not only the active one), the search processes can literally be conducted in a fraction of the time otherwise required.